# Negative option value

Tags: graphing-functions, finance

I have an exercise where I need to replicate the following graph:

[image]

with my own parameters. To do this I use:

$\begin{align*}
\text{Call option value} =SN(d_1)-Ee^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)
\end{align*}$

where 
$\begin{align*}
d_1 = & \dfrac{log(S/E)+ \left(r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}
\end{align*}$,
$\begin{align*}
d_2 =& d_1 - \sigma\sqrt{T-t}
\end{align*}$

and $N(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function for the standardized Normal distribution.

I set $E=110$, $r=8\%$, $T=1 year$, $t=0$ and $\sigma=0,4$ and calculate the call option value for different values of $S$. When I plot my results I get the following:

[image]

But I get negative option values, which I don't get and I can't see what I am doing wrong. I have checked everything but I cannot find the error?

Here is a screen shot of the values I get, I just used the formula to calculate the values in each column. Sorry about the screen shot, I don't know how to post an excel document on here.

[image]

I hope that some of you might find out what I have done wrong.

**UPDATE!**

I had another exercise where I had to varify that the call option value is 6,14. I had everything except for the option value, so this was pretty easy. I used the same excel document to calculate this and I get the correct result:

[image]

so it's not the formula. Is it my parameters then?

Comment: I see that in one of the excerpts from the spreadsheet you have constant volatility in a gray box and varying values of $S$ in the left-hand column, but in the other excerpt it is constant $S$ in the gray box and varying volatility in the left-hand column. That means your formulas for $d_1$, $d_2$, and $V(Call)$ must be quite different (input variables from different places, and different schemes for which variables come from a fixed row address). I will take a wild guess that you put volatility instead of $S$ into $V(Call)$ in the first example.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I already checked that by writing the other parameters in the other formula and see if I get the same result and I do.

Comment: I found out what I did wrong! 
My columns with $d_1$ and $d_2$ are calculated for different values of $S$  BUT my $V(call)$ is only calculated correctly for the first $S$, since I locked it on that value so when I dragged the bow down to get the results for other $S$ values I was actually calculating for the same value.

Comment: That would explain how you could get the right answer when trying just one value. So it was V(Call) but not for the reason I thought. (I did say "wild guess"!)

Comment: Haha, it was a great guess made me check everything again for the 5525 time. Oh my head feels much better now. Thank you :)